# How to append and print Numbers from a text file?

Tags: linux, bash, list, printf, text-files

I need to start from `file.txt`, which contains entries like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I need to print the following:

```
1,100
2,100
3,100
4,100
5,100
```

I have attempted this, but am receiving an invalid number error:

```
printf '%d,100\n' "$(< file.txt)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the rare occurrences of "too many quotes". Observe:

```
$ cat file.txt
1
2
3
4
5
$ var=$(< file.txt)
$ echo "$var"        # Quotes preserve original whitespace
1
2
3
4
5
$ echo $var          # No quotes reduce all whitespace to single spaces
1 2 3 4 5
```

The quotes make `echo` "see" just a single argument, namely the formatted file contents. Without the quotes, every line becomes an argument to `echo`, and they're printed separated by just spaces.

So, you can solve your problem with

```
$ printf '%d,100\n' $(< file.txt)
1,100
2,100
3,100
4,100
5,100
```

Another solution would be to use sed:

```
$ sed 's/$/,100/' file.txt
1,100
2,100
3,100
4,100
5,100
```

This substitutes the end of the line, `$`, with `,100`, for each line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
while read in; do echo "$in,100"; done < file.txt
```

Your error is caused by `printf` getting the whole file at once and not line by line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s,100\n", $0}' file
1,100
2,100
3,100
4,100
5,100
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
( set -f; set -- $(< file.txt)
  printf '%d,100\n' "$@" )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
seq 6 | awk '$0=$0",100"'  
1,100
2,100
3,100
4,100
5,100
6,100
```